# Javascript / Google Charts - Add marker filters to google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, filter

I am trying to make a map that will populate markers of locations based on dropdown options that are selected. I have a half working jsfiddle found here

http://jsfiddle.net/kamelkid2/drytwvL8/77/

Basically the end result is the user can select if they want to view playgrounds that are best suited by age group and/or playgrounds with baby swings. the resulting markers will populate on the map

i can get the first marker filter to work properly

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">BEST FOR (SHOW ALL)</option>
    <option value="BABIES">BEST FOR BABIES</option>
    <option value="TODDLERS">BEST FOR TODDLERS</option>
    <option value="KIDS">BEST FOR KIDS</option>
    <option value="ALL">BEST FOR ALL</option>
</select>
```

here is the filter

```
filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

however the second marker filter will not function across the many attempts i have tried. Is it possible to filter off of 2 dropdowns or is there another strategy I should be attempting?

the linked jsfiddle pretty much has my best attempt but I am not very adept at javascript yet so I am hoping to get a little guidance on a small little project for my wife's mommy group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot two things:

1.You forgot to add `categorybs` to the marker, you only added `category`:

```
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        categorybs: categorybs, //add this line
        map: map
    });
```

2.Your filterMarkersBS function worked with `category` instead of `categorybs`. You need to update it like this:

```
filterMarkersBS = function (categorybs) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.categorybs == categorybs || categorybs.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Working code:

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'Cascade Park - 130 Lynn Dr, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.234830, -81.453479, 'KIDS', 'BSNO'],
    ['1', 'Hudson Springs Park - 7095 Stow Rd, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.250798, -81.407120, 'BABIES', 'BSYES'],
    ['2', 'Middleton Park - 1708 Middleton Rd, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.268963, -81.450649, 'ALL', 'BSNO']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.234830, -81.453479);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var categorybs = marker[5];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        categorybs: categorybs,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

filterMarkersBS = function (categorybs) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.categorybs == categorybs || categorybs.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false"});
      </script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">BEST FOR (SHOW ALL)</option>
    <option value="BABIES">BEST FOR BABIES</option>
    <option value="TODDLERS">BEST FOR TODDLERS</option>
    <option value="KIDS">BEST FOR KIDS</option>
    <option value="ALL">BEST FOR ALL</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkersBS(this.value);">
    <option value="">BABY SWINGS (SHOW ALL)</option>
    <option value="BSYES">HAS BABY SWINGS</option>
    <option value="BSNO">DOES NOT HAVE BABY SWINGS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe I can proceed with the additional changes I need to make. Cheers